# Moderator variable in ANOVA

Tags: interaction

I am currently writing a research proposal and have to briefly state which statistical test I will use to analyse my data. I have only had one introductory course in statistical analysis and am therefore quite unsure of the appropriate test.

The experiment is a between-subjects experiment with two conditions (experimental and control) and I want to examine whether an IV (exposure to health information) has an effect on one DV (subsequent food consumption). However, I also want to examine whether socioeconomic status (low/medium/high) moderates the effect of the IV on the DV.

I would be so grateful for any advice on what tests I need to use.
Kindly, B